# How to deal with option set in Dynamics CRM API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamics-crm

I'm using this [gem](https://github.com/TinderBox/dynamics_crm) to connect my platform to the Dynamics CRM API. 
I have an attribute `neos_titre` which is the civility of my users, in Dynamics this attribute is an `OptionSet` and it need to be set by an integer. 
But create a user with :

`client.create('contact', firstname: 'test', neos_titre: 115170001)`

returns following error :

`DynamicsCRM::XML::Fault: s:Sender[] Incorrect attribute value type System.Int32`

So I don't know how to set this value, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i finally found the solution.

It works with :

`client.create('contact', lastname: 'test', neos_titre: {type: "OptionSetValue", value: 115170000})`

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

It should be `new OptionSetValue(115170001)` in native CRM Sdk.

When I checked the below implementation in git `client.rb` file, I feel it’s missing.

```
# These are all the operations defined by the Dynamics WSDL.
# Tag names are case-sensitive.
def create(entity_name, attributes)
  entity = XML::Entity.new(entity_name)
  entity.attributes = XML::Attributes.new(attributes)

  xml_response = post(organization_endpoint, create_request(entity))
  Response::CreateResult.new(xml_response)
end
```

You may fork it to add this or reach out to the contributors.